# Don't understand way algorithm is described in paper about Monte Carlo algorithm

Tags: algorithms, integers, monte-carlo

I'm reading [An Improved Monte Carlo Factorization Algorithm](https://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~brent/pd/rpb051i.pdf) by Richard P. Brent. I'm not sure I'm understanding some of the notation correctly. [image: screen shot of algorithm description]

To my understanding $x_0$ is an arbitrary starting point and is often 2. Is this correct?

I don't understand the syntax involving `repeat`, `for` and `do`. For example does everything on the `repeat` line get done repeatedly until the `until` condition is met? It doesn't make sense to me repeatedly setting `x` to `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repeat ... until` forms a *block* -- every after the `repeat` is to be repeated `until` the condition specified by `until` is met.  For the first `repeat` the last line of the block is $G = \mbox{GCD}(q,N); k = k+m$.  For `repeat...until` everything in the block is executed at least once as the `until` condition is only checked when it is met.

`for...do` works the same way, though here if the `for` statement needs more than one line `begin...end` is being used to contain all the work that the `for...do` needs to do.  So in your first `for...do` everything in on one line, but for the second there is a block of two lines following that are affected.

Keep an eye on the indentation: things indented to the same level are expected to be in the same block.  So the `for...do` in the first place is *inside* the `repeat...until` and will be executed by the `repeat` until the `until` condition is met.

Comment: Ok thanks! At the beginning it has $y=x_o$ what is $x_o$ is it 2? Also is the function $f$ just an arbitrary function which is usually taken to be $x^2+1$ ?

Comment: Take a look at section 5 of the paper you've linked -- the author gives a condition there for helping you to choose $f$ and $x_0$.  However, in general with these kinds of algorithms, you can pick $x_0$ freely and the algorithm should still converge to the answer.  $f$ might need a little more thought, but $x^2+1$ and $x^2-1$ look like good starting points.  If you're implementing this, make sure $f$ and $x_0$ are easy to change :)

Comment: Beside the first `until...` I don't understand where the `r := 2 x r` goes? Does it happen (once) after the repeat has ended or is it done each time the `until` is checked?

Comment: It happens once after that repeat is ended, but before the previous repeat ends (note that there’s another ‘until’ immediately after it). It is used as a check condition in the first until ($k\geq r$) so you can’t change it inside that repeat

Comment: In the for loops do you know if the range is inclusive on both ends? For example `for i := 1 to r` will `i` hold the value in $[1, r]$ or $[1, r)$ ?

Comment: Inclusive on both ends.  Typically *for* loops are inclusive unless otherwise specified, and if you look at the algorithm you'll see that the first loop is from $1$ to $1$ (because $r$ is initialised to $1$)

Comment: What is supposed to happen if $N$ is prime? I tested the algorithm and for some prime N $failure$ happens but for other prime N, $ys=f(ys)$ cycles through the same values and the `until G>1` never happens. I know $N$ is required to be composite, but is the algorithm supposed to fail in any particular way if it's not?

Comment: if $N$ is prime the algorithm should fall through and print *success*.  The condition of the *repeat...until* blocks is that $G>1$ and $G=\mbox{gcd}(q,N)$ which will be $1$ for prime $N$ unless $q=N$.  So when $G=1$ each loop goes through once, then you test against $G=N$ a couple of times, and fall out to *success* -- $N$ is prime

Comment: I don't quite follow. As you said when $N$ is prime G=1. So the $repeat$ will never stop because G>1 never happens. What loops are you referring to when you say "when G=1 each loop goes through once"?

Comment: sorry, you're right; the until keeps going when $G=1$.  The first loop updates $q$ so this should terminate for prime $N$ when $q=N$.  In the second loop, $G$ gets updated and should terminate when $G$ reaches $N$.  Without implementing the algorithm myself I couldn't tell you what the behaviour is for prime $N$ any better than that

Comment: @northerner Did you give me a bounty?  You really didn't have to do that!  Thank-you, obviously, but I'm helping you because you asked, not because I'm chasing rep points :)

Comment: That's because of your continued support with comments  which BTW I got another :)

Comment: With regards to $repeat$ you mentioned "everything in the block is executed at least once". I tested it out and found this goes into an infinite loop for some large primes (e.g. $101$). I tried testing the condition $until G > 1$ before the first iteration and it worked ($failure$ happened for each prime I tested).  I got the idea from Cesareo's answer since his checks the $G > 1$ each time. Any thoughts? Are you sure it's supposed to happen at least once?

Comment: I view `repeat...until` as the same as `do...while` but I see that Cesareo treats it as a `while` loop where the condition is tested at the start not the end.  But then I went and checked the paper again, and it's from $1980$.  So it's definitely possible that the condition is intended to be checked first (and if you tested it and it works, then keep it that way!); it's also possible that the author made a mistake when picking the control structure for the pseudo-code.  I'd annotate your copy of the paper with the correct point for checking for future reference though :)

Answer (score 1):

Please note the `y` is substituted `f(y)` on every iteration of the internal `repeat .. until` loop, so on each execution of `x := y` a different value is assigned to `x`.

In the language of mathematics we would say we have a sequence of some approximations or other values, and denote it with an indexed symbols like $x_i$. In the algorithm, however we do not need past values, just the most recent one. Hence we do not store all values in some indexed array, instead we just overwrite the same variable again and again with the value we currently need.

Answer (score 0):

Attached a python realization for the proposed algorithm. The **repeat** was substituted by a **while** with the condition complemented. The N are **prime** numbers that should give **failure** as output.

```
from fractions import gcd

def mod(m,n):
    return m % n

def f(x,N):
    return mod(x**2+3,N)

y = 0
r = 1
q = 1
G = 0
m = 1
N = 99398833
N = 22801763489
N = 252097800623
N = 2760727302517
N = 29996224275833



while G <= 1:
    x = y

    for i in range(r):
        y = f(y,N)

    k = 0

    while  (k < r and G <= 1):
        ys = y

        for i in range(min(m,r-k)):
            y = f(y,N)
            q = mod(q*abs(x-y),N)

        G = gcd(q,N)
        k = k + m

    r = 2*r

if G == N:

    while G <= 1:
        ys = f(ys,N)
        G  = gcd(abs(x-ys),N)

if G == N:
    print("failure")
else:
    print("success")
```

Comment: Why did you use while loop instead of do-while? Isn't it supposed to happen at least once?

Comment: I didn't used the **do** loop because the number of times to perform depends on one condition, which is not  a fixed number.

Comment: This is why I ask the question about the notation. Isn't it correct that `repeat...until` happens at least once? Hence a `do` loop is a better fit than a `while`?

Comment: In python we have two ways to implement loops. With **for** or with **while**. Concerning your doubt, you have reason because the hypothetical **repeat until** always executes once at least. In the **while** loops presented in the script, we make a priori $G = 0$ to force the loop initiation because at the very beginning $G$ is undefined. Any way: each programming language has it's own building blocks and should be used at their best.